# Golang interface{} parameter how to judge pass value or pass pointer

Tags: go

When I learn go language, I was confused by `interface{} parameter`

for example, I use the net/rpc

the interface is:

```
// description: Call invokes the named function, waits for it to complete, and returns its error status.
func (client *Client) Call(serviceMethod string, args interface{}, reply interface{}) error
```

I just pass the reply parameter as value, the program will error:
`rpc call error:reading body gob: attempt to decode into a non-pointer`

so how to distinguish when I should pass pointer or pass value for the interface.

Answer (score 1):

The `interface{}` type for a function argument indicates, that you can pass value with any type to that argument. That is because all types implements `interface{}` (empty interface).  This also includes a pointer type as well.

Because of that, You cannot judge whether you need to pass pointer or value based on the `interface{}` type declaration of that argument alone. Because It will accept both. So, you need to consult documentation of the specific function, and see what author expects.

In your case, the error is defined at https://golang.org/src/encoding/gob/decoder.go As the error says, decoder need a pointer for the `reply parameter`. Otherwise, the `reply` won't get back to the caller.